# JRockit Mission Control on Mac OS X to Connect to a Remote JVM

Tags: macos, jvm, jrockit

How does one connect to and monitor a remote JVM using JRockit Mission Control during a load test? Flags? Settings?

I am on Mac OS 10.6.8. I can "ssh -X" to the server and run JRMC on the box, but it consumes 40-50% of the CPU. I didn't see an installer for JRMC on Mac OS X here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We started building Mac versions of JRockit Mission Control 4.1.0, but since JRockit is not available on Mac, we never released the RCP application version. However, for Mac there is the option to run Mission Control as Eclipse plugins. Go to the Mission Control update site and follow the instructions.

Long term, we are working on making Mission Control available on Hotspot. When we make Mission Control generally available on Hotspot, there will definitely be a Mac version.

Comment: Thanks @Hirt. I look forward to it. Is there a site where I can watch for progress? Let me know if you need beta testers (_:

Comment: Now we have Java Mission Control, but you probably already know that. :)